# What does model means in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
loss_batch, _, summary = sess.run([model.loss, model.optimizer, model.summary_op], 
                                  feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I found this code snippet in this [Stanford Lecture Note](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wqp8_-H06oE4zB9CHDwzTx5BfAOMM_6nnNJMSfkazkU/edit?usp=sharing) on **"word2vec + manage experiments"**

Here what does a `model` reference to?

Comment: this complete code https://github.com/karthikmswamy/SentimentClassifier/blob/master/04_word2vec_visualize.py might help

Answer (score 0):

The process of training an ML model involves providing an ML algorithm (that is, the learning algorithm) with training data to learn from. The term ML model refers to the model artifact that is created by the training process